# How to get a Bitmap from an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

I wish to get a `Bitmap` from an `ImageView` loaded with `Glide` like such:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(URL)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(my_imageView);
```

I have tried the following:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

and

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

And none of them has worked for me so far.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't know Glide, but the best answer would be to get the bitmap from Glide. If that is not possible, create a `Bitmap` of the proper size, wrap that in a `Canvas`, and ask your `ImageView` to `draw()` to the `Canvas`. The `Bitmap` will contain the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, this is a simple error. You need to add this before the code where you are trying to get Bitmap out of the ImageView:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

In order to get the `Bitmap` out of the ImageView using DrawingCache, you first need to `enable` ImageView to draw image cache.

then:

```
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Also, calling `buildDrawingCache();` is equivalent to calling `buildDrawingCache(false);`

Comment: This helped, but when I load a new picture in the `ImageView` and display it, it displays the first Bitmap saved. Is that caused by the cache?

Comment: why don't you try using imageView.destroyDrawingCache(); before setting the other image.

Comment: It's great to hear that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Things have changed, and the answers here need updating.  So here's my solution in kotlin.  This is simplified, no synthetics or view binding (hehe).

```
    val imageView : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.my_imageview)
    val bitmap : Bitmap = imageView.drawable.toBitmap()
```

You need to make sure that the ImageView has had time to draw before doing this.  `onViewCreated()` in a Fragment or after a click event is a good time to do this.  The overhead shouldn't be too much.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem that the bitmap still always resulted in null (even though using the drawing cache, probably some race with the Facebook ShareButton/ShareContent) so I had the following solution to make sure that glide was done loading the image:

Add a listener to glide

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .listener(listener)
        .into(imageView);
```

The Listener

```
private RequestListener listener = new RequestListener() {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Object resource, Object model, Target target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resource).getBitmap();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can easily avoid casting inside listener if you use Glide `.asBitmap()`

Answer (score 2):

presently `setDrawingCacheEnabled` has been **deprecated**, so another solution is using

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Or to obtain `Bitmap` from `Uri`, we can use the *Glide* library.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(this) //taking as bitmap
                     .load(uri //Uri)
                     .asBitmap()
                     .into(100, 100) //width and height
                     .get();
```

Using *Glide* is quite good for handling `bitmaps`. Refer the docs at [Handling Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/)